# Is there a way place submit button of a form inside another view?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

My problem is as following:
I have a controller called "SettingController" contains a view called SSO.cshtml, and there is a form in it. I also have a controller called "UserController" contains view "Index.cshtml". Index view has button "Submit". In UserController there is a HttpPost method call SyncSSO() return ActionResult. I want to make button "Submit" become submit button of form in SSO.cshtml and after clicking it, an instance of model contains information of fields of this form will be sent to SyncSSO(). Is there a way like that?

Comment: You can use Javascript/JQuery/AJAX to achieve this

Comment: Can you explain detail? If you have some sudo code, I will understand your idea easily

Comment: You can invoke controller action from Javascript using AJAX. So you need to write JS code which will be in invoke on click of button. The code will prepare data from the form, using JQuery, to be posted and make a POST request to the controller action via AJAX and handler the response coming back from the controller action..

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/337dfd/useful-way-to-call-controller-actions-from-html-using-jquery/

Comment: https://haacked.com/archive/2011/08/18/calling-asp-net-mvc-action-methods-from-javascript.aspx/

Comment: But there is a problem. How can I get data of the form inside view SSO.cshtml while I'm in view Index.cshtml?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use ButtonType as Submit then it will Post all the data on the Page. and If you just want to POST few fields or only selected data then Go with AJAX call, which is better option.

Below is the example I have copy pasted:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("FirstAjax", "AjaxTest")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { a: "testing" },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() { alert('Success'); },
    error: errorFunc
});
```

Comment: But, how can I get data from the form inside view SSO.cshtml while I'm in view index.cshtml?

Comment: When you will post the data that time find it with help selector on the DOM. and the bind that data into the data which you are going to pass via AJAX call.